# How do I format currency in GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, number-formatting

I was wondering how I can format the output to 2 decimals.  This code worked perfectly when I wasn't using a GUI but now it doesn't seem to work at all.  I'm not getting any compile errors and I imported `import java.text.NumberFormat;` at the top.  Any tips to get this thing working?

```
//sytem output
        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        defaultFormat.format(monthlyPayment);
        txtMonthlyPayment.setText(Double.toString(monthlyPayment));
```

Comment: You're throwing away the result of your formatting.

Comment: Well, it didn't throw it away in my previous project when I wasn't using the GUI.  What code would I use instead?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing some java basics.

```
    defaultFormat.format(monthlyPayment);
```

Will return a formatted string, which you assign to nothing and it therefore goes into the swirling chaos of the center universe where that amorphous blight of nethermost confusion which blasphemes and bubbles at the center of all infinity—the boundless daemon sultan Azathoth, whose name no lips dare speak aloud, and who gnaws hungrily in inconceivable, unlighted chambers beyond time and space and there your unassigned String value will interrupt the muffled, maddening beating of vile drums and the thin monotonous whine of accursed flutes which keeps Azathoth slumbering, hence allowing him to awaken and consume all of creation.

If you had instead used

```
txtMonthlyPayment.setText(defaultFormat.format(monthlyPayment));
```

The universe might have been spared...

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this instead.

```
    NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    txtMonthlyPayment.setText(defaultFormat.format(monthlyPayment));
```